# When I'm using transitionWithView other gestureRecognizers dont work

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewanimationtransition

When i use transitionWithView: on one of my subViews (flip from left), all of my gestureRecognizers (of different subViews) dont work until the transition animation is over.
It fills like the app is stuck.
I know I can't put it in a different thread, but is there a way to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to enable user interactions during animations.

See here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW112

Comment: That was so easy, i dont know how i missed it. Thanks

Comment: Welcome. You might want to accept that as the correct answer if it helped you.